# Python Selenium でドロップダウンが選択できません

Tags: python, wordpress, selenium

WordPressの管理画面を Python Selenium で自動操作を試みているところですが、
見事にハマってしまいました。ご教示のほどよろしくお願いします。

■ 自動操作のプロセス

① WordPress 管理画面にログイン（OK）

② プラグインの操作画面に移動（OK）

[image: 画像]

③ CSVファイルのアップロード（OK）

④ アップロード後に表示されるドロップダウンメニューの選択（現在ここで躓いています）

[![画像][3]][3]

手動であれば、下図のようにメニューの選択ができます。

[image: 画像]

コードは、下記のように書きました。

```
# coding: utf-8   
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium import webdriver
import pyautogui
from time import sleep

# ブラウザは、Chrome を使用
browser = webdriver.Chrome()

# プラグインの画面に移動
browser.get(wai1url)
sleep(5)

# csvファイルをアップロード
browser.find_element_by_link_text(u"ファイルをアップロードする").click()
sleep(2)
pyautogui.typewrite('link_20')
sleep(3)
pyautogui.press('down')
sleep(1)
pyautogui.press('return')
sleep(2)

#
# csvファイルのアップロード後、ドロップダウンが表示されます。AJAX？
#

# ページをスクロール
browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

# 下記コードは機能しました。
browser.find_element_by_link_text(u"既存の項目").click()
sleep(3)
browser.find_element_by_link_text(u"新規の項目").click()
sleep(3)

# ドロップダウンメニューの選択（機能しません）
select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('custom_type_selector'))

for index in range(len(select.options)):
    select = Select(browser.find_element_by_name('custom_type_selector'))
    select.select_by_index(4) # select Users
```

ドロップダウンのHTMLは、下記の通りです。

```
<select name="custom_type_selector" id="custom_type_selector" class="wpallimport-post-types">

<option value="post" data-imagesrc="dashicon dashicon-post" selected="selected">投稿</option>

<option value="page" data-imagesrc="dashicon dashicon-page" >固定ページ</option>

<option value="taxonomies" data-imagesrc="dashicon dashicon-taxonomies" >Taxonomies</option>

<option value="import_users" data-imagesrc="dashicon dashicon-import_users" >Users</option>

</select>
```

他にもいくつか試してみました。

[ 1 ]

```
s1 = Select(browser.find_element_by_id('custom_type_selector'))
s1.select_by_index(4)
```

結果：selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on 　＜select＞ elements, not on ＜div＞

[ 2 ]

```
s1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='wpallimport-choose-import-direction']/select/option[@value='post']")

s1.click()
```

結果：　Message: no such element: Unable to locate element･･･

[ 3 ]

```
s1 = browser.find_element_by_id('custom_type_selector')
for option in s1.find_elements_by_tag_name('option'):
    if option.text == 'Users':
        option.click()
        sleep(60)
        break
```

このように色々トライしてみましたが、同じようなエラーばかりです。

ただ普通のHTMLページだと、

```
driver.get("http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dropdown")
s1 = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('dropdown'))
s1.select_by_index(4)
```

このようにすれば、ドロップダウンメニューを選択できるのですが・・・。

ぜひ、お助けください

Comment: ご指摘のとおり、DOMツリーを見てみたところ、
ドロップダウンの要素は下記のような感じになっていました。

＜div＞
　　＜div＞
　　＜a＞
　　＜label＞投稿＜/label＞
　　＜/a＞
　　＜/div＞
　＜ul＞
　　＜li＞
　　＜a＞
　　＜label＞User＜/label＞
　　＜/a＞
　　＜/li＞
　＜/ul＞
＜/div＞

この要素にしたがってコードを書き直したところ機能しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ドロップダウンメニューのHTMLコードを誤解されています。
HTMLソースではなく、開発者ツールなどで確認できるDOMツリーを見ましょう。

HTMLソースでは `<select>` 要素ですが、
画面の表示時に `<div>` 要素に置き換えられています。
ですから、単純に `<div>` をクリックするコードを書けば良いです。
これは [ 1 ] で表示されているエラーもヒントになります。

Comment: 教えて頂きありがとうございます！DOMツリーを見て、コードを書き直してみます。